# Printing first 50 numbers with 5 rows and 10 cols

Tags: c

I want to print the first 49 numbers with 5 rows and 10 columns.

[image: Example]

I've tried using certain width implications and trying to make it aligned but I couldn't figure out how.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int i, j;
   int count = 50;
   int r = 5;
   int c = 10;

   for (i = 0; i <= r; i++)
   {
     for(int j = 1; j <=count; j++)
     {
       printf("%9d", i);
       i++;
     }
   }

   return (0);
}
```

I was able to print from 0-49 but it wasn't aligned correctly, can someone help? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "vertically aligned"? Can you edit your post to show the exact output as a code block (indent 4 spaces, use ``` backtick fences or Ctrl+K to make the code monospace). Thank you.

Comment: Read the documentation for `printf` more carefully. If you've only looked at an introductory treatment in a textbook, look at a full description. That function does a *lot* of things, if you know how to *tell it what you want*.

Comment: There isn't any vertical alignment, because the output is all on one line. Anything seen as vertical (non-)alignment is because of the output automatically wrapping to the next line. A terminal/console width is often a multiple of `8`, so `printf("%89d", i);` might look better.

Comment: @ggorlen changes made!

Comment: Sorry about the typo - `printf("%8d", i);`

Comment: The output is still unclear. Please don't post an image of the output--it's impossible to tell what the whitespace is and is not friendly to folks with screen readers. Please edit the post to include a code block of text showing your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one loop and can use the remainder operator to detect when a new line is needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int count = 50;
   int columns = 10;

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       printf("%9d", i);

       if ((i % columns) == 9)
       {
           printf("\n");
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
    0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9
   10       11       12       13       14       15       16       17       18       19
   20       21       22       23       24       25       26       27       28       29
   30       31       32       33       34       35       36       37       38       39
   40       41       42       43       44       45       46       47       48       49
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use two loops, one will do fine.

1. Use "%2d" to reserve two digits for each number.
2. Don't increase for loop variable inside loop. It isn't of much use here.

## Code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i, j;
   int count = 50;
   int c = 10;

   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       printf("%2d ", i);
       if (i%c == 9) printf("\n");
   }

   return (0);
}
```

Comment: Using `puts("")` or even better `putc('\n')` is preferred over `printf("\n")`.

Comment: @alk `puts("");` adds a new line automatically, but I can't seem to find out why is it preferred or even better than `printf()` ? Because it is short, or there is some reason which I have no idea of!?

Comment: Using functions prepared to do *formatted* output to just print a string is misuse in the boadest sense, to print a `char` only, which a new-line is, seem almost wrong to me.

Comment: @alk Seems somewhat reasonable! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know if the column has printed 10 values,you will need a offset to remind you that, where the last element occured which was the last 10th value, so we assign the `offset` variable to that element value based on 10 columns per row, so we take modulus if its the completely divisible by 10, then we will move to next row

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int count = 0;
   int row = 5;
   int column = 9;
   int offset = 0;

  for (int outer = 0; outer <= row; outer++)
   {
     for(int inner = offset; inner <= column; inner++)
     {
       if(count>=50){
        break;
      }
       printf("%9d", count); // tab spaces between colums
       count++;

     }
      printf("\n"); // new lines 
   }
   return (0);
}
```

Comment: sorry @alk it was a typo error, `offset = j+1`; i have fixed it.

Comment: The code only prints 45 numbers. Testing is an art ... ;>

Comment: Yeah, agreed Testing is quite the art, prevents from getting a down vote :v, updated the code and tested it

Comment: Proposing to use `putc('\n')` instead of `printf("\n")`.

Comment: Sure it does. Just mind that it takes a character, which need single quotes as opposed to a string which needs double quotes.

Comment: OK, my bad. It should be `putc('\n', stdout);`.

Answer (score -1):

Adding space or any character before "%9d" fixes the problem.

```
   printf(" %9d", i);
```

[image: Output when the above line is used]

Comment: Where do the new-lines come from?

Comment: New lines are the artifact of windows 10 prompt. It automatically adds newlines and doesn't allow the user to be maximize to full screen.